# Font suggestion(motion/speed/sports)

Tags: fonts

I am looking for an oblique, slanted font that suggest motion/speed/sports but in a very subtle way.

What I was thinking of is something like any font in italic mode but instead of the text leaning on the *right side* it should lean the opposite way. I hope you understand what I mean.

Suggestions ?

something like this only better :D   :

[image]

Comment: do you know Photoshop or illustrator? you can make such speedy motion text with the help of them..PS and AI have lots of effects.....

Comment: yes... im working on it... but for some reason it just doesn't look right... there's something odd about oblique text... I'm doing it in illustrator using the Transform panel and the Shear thingy there, its in degrees° and stuff...

Comment: Oblique fonts, at least professional ones, aren't just slanted. There are subtle changes to make it look right, particularly to do with line widths. I suspect if you start with a quality  right-leaning oblique and shear it so it leans left, you'll have better results.

Answer (score 2):

German bicycle manufacturer [Canyon](http://www.canyon.com/_en/roadbikes/series/aeroad-cf.html) has an unusual logo treatment along those lines.  Note that the correct term for this and your sample is oblique (= slanted), not italic ( = cursive and slanted). Leaning to the left is sometimes called reverse-oblique.

[image: Canyon bicycle showing reverse oblique logo]
<sub>(source: [besportier.com](http://www.besportier.com/archives/canyon-v-drome-al-track-racing-bike-will-definitly-turn-heads-1.jpg))</sub>

Another German bicycle manufacturer, [Nicolai](http://www.nicolai.net/14-1-Home.html) use might be termed a mirrored-reverse-oblique.

[image]

Comment: interesting... ^ ^

Answer (score 2):

Here are some fonts who are tagged with the word speed:
http://www.fontspace.com/category/speed

I bet if you google a little you can find a lot that you like :)

Comment: Those don't seem to be very subtle.